# Subjunctive 'were' in concrete sentence

Tags: subjunctives

I need help.

Can I use 'were' here. The condition the speaker has is not an illness.

> If it wasn't for the spiritual practice that initiated it I would be convinced that it **were**(?) a serious illness and that I would be hopelessly lost.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the use of `were` is correct here. Why would you think it is incorrect? The condition of the speaker has hardly got anything to do with it IMO.

Comment: MS Word 2016 underlined in red, hence I wasn't sure whether 'is' would be the more appropriate option.

Comment: @satnam - I disagree. If anything it is the other way around, e.g. "If it *weren't* for ... I would be convinced that it *was* serious ..." In other words I agree with MS Word and James K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subjective could be put in the conditional clause

> If it weren't for the spiritual practice...

But the conclusion should have indicative, and perhaps the past tense:

> ...I would be convinced that it was a serious illness...

A comma to separate the clauses would help readers.

However, the subjunctive is not required in modern English.